# is there a way to extract the query from Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report XI Release 2.

I have around 200+ Crystal Reports. How can i extract the queries associated with the report for 200+ reports..

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way other than writing your own application to handle it. Do you have any visual studio .NET skills?

Comment: yes- see http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.sap.km.cm.docs/oss_notes_boj/sdn_oss_boj_bi/sap%28bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==%29/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes%7B6163636573733d36393736354636443646363436353344333933393338323636393736354637333631373036453646373436353733354636453735364436323635373233443330333033303331333233383330333533313335%7D.do